# Sorting objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models `Description` and `Click`. `Description` has many `Clicks`.
How can I sort `Descriptions` by column in `Click`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try...

```
Description.joins(:click).order('click.column_name')
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to call .all before your joins condition, like so:

`Description.all.joins(:click).order('click.column_name')`

Comment: @HassebAhmad I got error: `Association named 'click' was not found on Description; perhaps you misspelled it?`
But relationships are done well cause when I create click it has description id and everything works good.

Comment: Change click to clicks has many relationship names are pluralized